# How to execute a job manually with injected dependencies

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I need to execute a job in the context of the Play application. I have to do it manually because I don't know when I'll need to run it. The problem is that I don't know exactly how to do it. The job have some dependencies, so they need to be injected as they are in the common controllers. Then, the job will need to be called manually, and executed with the injected dependencies.

Is this possible? Is there a correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer : yes it is possible. The idea is to have your job (or a factory for the job) as an injected dependency to the controller, which is executed when an action of the controller is executed.
Without you providing code with an explicit problem,it is difficult to vive an answer with precise directions though.